# Should [personal-likeness] be a tag synonym of [right-of-publicity]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems to me that [personal-likeness](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-likeness) should be a synonym of  [right-of-publicity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right-of-publicity)?. They seem to have essentially the same meaning, and the User Guidance for the former is:

> This tag is for questions about the publicity rights in a person's image or likeness

Whereas the latter's is:

> The right of individuals to control commercial use and benefits from their identity or likeness

But neither has very many questions, and I do not have enough points in the tag to formally propose a synonym. Can someone else, perhaps a Mod, make this change?

Comment: Yes, I support this proposal.